# Github - Is it possible to work with only one branch on different computers

Tags: git, version-control, github

So I finally set up my first Github repo, and the reason is that I have multiple working machines, and I'd like to have a way to sync up all my work somewhere. I have my project set up on Eclipse so I'm using EGit to connect to github.

I first shared my project on my main working machine(call this machine 1) to github, and then I imported the project form github on machine 2. On machine 2 I noticed there's something called "Remote Tracking", which contains one branch called 'origin/master'. I assume this is the main branch on github, and this is the branch I want to work with.

However, whenever I want to select it as my active branch, it'll ask me to create a new "Local" branch, where my changes go instead of the origin/master branch. The 'local' branch shows up as an individual branch on GitHub, and changes to that branch won't merge with master branch unless I tell it so

Does this mean if I choose to work on different machines, each machine will have to create it's own branch? I find that annoying because I'll always have go **commit to local branch**->**manually merge 2 branches**. Any way to commit to main branch directly?

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't have to do that. When cloning the code from the github on the second machine, it should have created a local master branch tracking origin/master. So, just work on this `master` branch (which is the default one) on your second machine, and when ready, `push` it on the server.

When going back to your first machine, `pull` and you'll merge (or fast forward) the changes from the server on the local `master` branch. Make some changes, commit, push again. Then go back to the second machine, and pull to merge the changes from the server.

git is a complex beast, and you should read a tutorial before using it. See http://git-scm.com/book/en for example.